# retrieve and store data in firebase folder wise

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

hi i want to render the data from the firestore in a react native app.client asked me to do render the data in folderwise .where it contains folder inside folder and files with folder.when user clicks the pdf files it pdf viewer should open .i implemented pdf viewer functionlity .for now i want to know how to render the data folderwise and when clicked on folder it needs to open data inside the folder ,if we click on file it needs to render pdf .please help me im not ettin how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FlatList`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const FoldersScreen = () => {
  const [folders, setFolders] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firestore()
      .collection('folders')
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const folders = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
          folders.push({
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
            key: documentSnapshot.id,
          });
        });
        setFolders(folders);
      });
    return () => subscriber();
  }, []);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    if (item.type === 'folder') {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('Open folder:', item.name)}>
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    } else if (item.type === 'file') {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('Open PDF:', item.name)}>
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={folders}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default FoldersScreen;
```

Comment: thanks can you please tell me how to store the data for this code to retrieve   in firestore with some example

Comment: Check second answer

Comment: Please if the first answer did the job, mark it as the accepted answer. Further, how did the solution in your second question? If it was useful, please again give it a plus... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To you second question:

```js
// Add a folder document with a subcollection of files
firestore().collection('folders').doc('folder1').set({
  name: 'Folder 1'
});
firestore().collection('folders').doc('folder1').collection('files').doc('file1').set({
  name: 'File 1',
  url: 'https://example.com/file1.pdf'
});
firestore().collection('folders').doc('folder1').collection('files').doc('file2').set({
  name: 'File 2',
  url: 'https://example.com/file2.pdf'
});
```